# AngularJS - Validate a part of a form

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 1.5.9

I have a big form, which I scattered through different Bootstrap Accordion.

When there is an error in the form, I want to be able to change the class of my accordions to show in which accordions the error is located.

To check for errors in a whole form, I can check

```
myFormName.$error
```

And to check errors for an element, I can simply do

```
myFormName.myInputName.$error
```

But I don't know if there is a way to do this for multiple element at once, without having to check each element individually.

My first thought was to change the name of my inputs like so:

```
<input name="accordion1.fieldName">
```

But this didn't give me the expected result: I don't have myFormName.accordion1.$error, actually, I don't even have myFormName.accordion1.fieldName, since my data is actually stored in myFormName['accordion1.fieldName'] which is pretty much useless.

Has anyone found an answer to this problem? I think I'll have to check each field, which is kinda ugly, and a mess to maintain whenever we add / remove fields...

Maybe there is a directive out there that could do that for me, but as a non-native English speaker, I can't find which key words to use for my search in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to nest with the [ng-form directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm):

```
<form name=form1>
    <div ng-form=set1>
       <input name=input1 />
       <input name=input2 />
    </div>
</form>

{{form1.set1.$error}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could name the fields with a prefix such as 'accordion1_' then add a controller function that will filter your fields.

```
ctrl.fieldGroup = function(form, fieldPrefix) {

    var fieldGroup = {};

    angular.forEach(form, function(value, key) {

        if (key.indexOf(prefix) === 0) {
            fieldGroup[key] = value;
        }

    });

    return fieldGroup;

}
```

Then `ctrl.fieldGroup('accordion1')` will return an object with the appriopriate fields on it. You could extend the function further to add an aggregate `$error` property to the resulting `fieldGroup` object.

Comment: That's what I would have gone for if I had no better solution, but with @georgeawg's solution, I won't have to add any code in my controllers, so I'll probably go for his method ^^'